# Reaction Diffusion Dithering App

Tags: vector, shapes, software-recommendation

On my instagram feed I stumbled upon an app that let's you do dithering that sort of looks like a reaction diffusion algorithm. I tried to find it, but only found Ivan Murits app [TexTuring](http://ivan-murit.fr/works.php?w=texturing), which is definitely not it.

I want to translate an image to a vector file that uses the reaction diffusion style to dither the image? How would you do that?

[image: Reaction Diffusion]

Comment: I figured if it was advertised to me, maybe somebody else saw it there aswell and can remember the name of the app.

Comment: The app I was looking for was: http://www.stochaster.org/en/welcome.html

Answer (score 2):

Hmm interesting. There's a filter in G'MIC for GIMP that can make a similar pattern from an image.

Once G'MIC is installed for GIMP, you'll find it listed under *Filters > G'MIC > Testing > Lylejk > Lylejk's Stencil*.  To get the effect you want, it's best if you desaturate the image first.

Screenshot of the filter in action

[image]

Result

[image]

Here's another one I made from random difference clouds generated in GIMP, then the same filer applied, but with a larger radius

[image]

From there you could autotrace the image into vectors in Illustrator/Inkscape etc.